# delete records from mongodb based on condition

Tags: mongodb

Hi I am new to mongodb and I don't know how can I achieve below efficiently as we have huge data in collection

I want to delete those documents which are older than 6 month
but same time I want to keep latest 5 record for each al_object_id even though there are older than 6 month.

```
+--------+---------------------+--------------+
| al_id  |       al_date       | al_object_id |
+--------+---------------------+--------------+
| 224917 | 2012-01-01 00:00:00 |            1 |
| 224918 | 2012-01-02 00:00:00 |            1 |
| 224919 | 2012-01-03 00:00:00 |            1 |
| 224920 | 2012-01-04 00:00:00 |            1 |
| 224921 | 2012-01-05 00:00:00 |            1 |
| 224922 | 2012-01-06 00:00:00 |            1 |
| 224923 | 2012-01-07 00:00:00 |            1 |
| 224925 | 2016-01-01 00:00:00 |          222 |
| 224926 | 2016-01-02 00:00:00 |          222 |
| 224927 | 2016-01-03 00:00:00 |          222 |
| 224928 | 2016-01-04 00:00:00 |          222 |
| 224929 | 2016-01-05 00:00:00 |          222 |
| 224930 | 2016-01-06 00:00:00 |          222 |
| 224931 | 2016-01-07 00:00:00 |          222 |
| 224932 | 2016-01-08 00:00:00 |          222 |
| 224933 | 2016-01-09 00:00:00 |          222 |
| 224934 | 2016-01-10 00:00:00 |          222 |
| 224935 | 2012-01-11 00:00:00 |          222 |
| 224936 | 2012-01-12 00:00:00 |          222 |
| 224937 | 2012-01-13 00:00:00 |          222 |
| 224938 | 2012-01-14 00:00:00 |          222 |
| 224939 | 2012-01-15 00:00:00 |          222 |
| 224940 | 2012-01-16 00:00:00 |          222 |
+--------+---------------------+--------------+
```

in case of record for object al_object_id  = 1 there is no new update in last 6 month so i want to keep latest 5 updates and remove others
where as for al_object_id = 222 there are updates in last 6 month so i want to remove records older than 6 month. so expected output will be as below

```
+--------+---------------------+--------------+
| al_id  |       al_date       | al_object_id |
+--------+---------------------+--------------+
| 224923 | 2012-01-07 00:00:00 |            1 |
| 224922 | 2012-01-06 00:00:00 |            1 |
| 224921 | 2012-01-05 00:00:00 |            1 |
| 224920 | 2012-01-04 00:00:00 |            1 |
| 224919 | 2012-01-03 00:00:00 |            1 |
| 224934 | 2016-01-10 00:00:00 |          222 |
| 224933 | 2016-01-09 00:00:00 |          222 |
| 224932 | 2016-01-08 00:00:00 |          222 |
| 224931 | 2016-01-07 00:00:00 |          222 |
| 224930 | 2016-01-06 00:00:00 |          222 |
| 224929 | 2016-01-05 00:00:00 |          222 |
| 224928 | 2016-01-04 00:00:00 |          222 |
| 224927 | 2016-01-03 00:00:00 |          222 |
| 224926 | 2016-01-02 00:00:00 |          222 |
| 224925 | 2016-01-01 00:00:00 |          222 |
+--------+---------------------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this would be using `aggregate` and `findAndModify`.

You can do the following:

1. sort by descending order of date. This can be done in the `$sort` stage of the `aggregate` method.
2. Use the `$group` stage in the same `aggregate` method to group by `al_object_id`. In this stage, use the `$push` operator to form an array of dates for a particular `al_object_id`. This should give you an array of `al_object_id`s along with dates for each.
3. Use another `$group` stage on the above result in the same `aggregate` method to find the fifth `al_date` using the `$slice` operator.
4. Now that you know, from the output of the above aggregation method, the date, (say dateThresh), before which elements should be deleted, you can use `findAndModify` method to delete those documents by looping over the `aggregate` result. Also,do not forget to handle this:

   ```
   if dateThresh < dateSixMonthsAgo:
     remove_all_elements_before_dateThresh
   else:
     remove_all_elements_before_dateSixMonthsAgo
   ```